# Laravel 5.2 quickstart instructions downloads incompatible 5.1 code

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, and tried to start with the 5.2 "quickstart" instructions at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#introduction . It told me to do this early on:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-intermediate quickstart
cd quickstart
composer install
php artisan migrate
```

But just a little farther along the instructions, all kinds of failures came up. I've tried on multiple machines, OSs, etc; never could get the quickstart to work. Then I bought a book (that shall remain nameless), which had far more detailed and very different instructions, but didn't work either. I tried with and without homestead; with apache or not; and all kinds of other variations.

Needless to say, this has not encouraged confidence in Laravel. Searches here and in general, found other similar issues but no answers.

So: why don't the instructions work? Especially the "official" ones, and especially the ones for the most basic "getting started" process?

Or perhaps better: Does anyone know of instructions that *do* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went ahead and followed the instructions you posted, and you are correct; by default, they are missing a few steps. After cloning the repository into whatever folder you want and running `composer install`, you need to configure your `.env` file to correctly match the setting you'll be using on your host. Specifically, the following lines need to be configured before `php artisan migrate` can run successfully:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Unless you have a database called `homstead` with a user `homestead` and the password `secret`, the migrate function will fail.

After modifying those, the next step would be to change the permissions on the `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders of your project. They need to be (at a minimum) writable by the application. You can use

```
chmod 775 -R storage
chmod 775 -R bootstrap/cache
// Use 775 should do it, but 777 will (though I don't recommend the use of 777)
```

After that is setup, you should be able to run `php artisan migrate` successfully. Note that before changing the permissions, it would be possible for the function to fail, but impossible to tell you that (as your `storage/logs` folder wouldn't be writable.

Once those steps are taken, you can now navigate to `http://localhost/quickstart/public` and you should see the following screen:

[image]

The last thing I usually do is symlink the `public` folder to something in my webroot so I don't have to access `quickstart/public` everytime:

```
ln -s /var/www/html/quickstart/public /var/www/html/quick
```

So, as you can see, the instructions are a little lacking in the installation and usage department, but I've learned these tricks from earlier versions of Laravel, and so far they have worked for installation of Laravel 5.2 apps.

Hope that gives you some insight, but let me know if you need anything else cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found at least one major problem:

The "git clone" command that the *5.2* doc tells you to use, clones incompatible *5.1* code!

This is not obvious from the code (esp. if you're new) For example, nowhere in the code does it say "5.1" (which seems a very obvious thing to do). Also, it's not that the URI points explicitly to the *wrong* version; the URI just doesn't mention a URI at all (I for one, would expect that such a URI would get the latest version) -- far safer to use a URI that's explicit, so if the URI in the doc were wrong, it would be *obviously* wrong.

I caught on when I got far enough to see that the 5.2 doc "quotes" the code in one place as being:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // Other Eloquent Properties...
```

but the actual code that git clone had given me was:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
```

Then I started retrieving other versions of the doc until I found the one that matched the code (it turned out to be 5.1).

Hoping that others can find this and not get burned the same way.